# Changing TextView size dynamically as per Word or Letter count

Tags: android, textview

I have an application which randomly selects from 3 arrays, and randomly selects one fact from the randomly chosen array.

The problem I face is with the TextView size, since some facts are longer than they can fit on the Layout on the displays, especially on devices with a low res screen.

Currently I believe the best workaround to this is to have a condition that changes the TextView size to a smaller size when the fact contains more than n letters (including spaces).

Here's the code to fetch the random string. How can I dynamically change the size now?

```
String[] Array = this.getResources().getStringArray(com.xyz.example.R.array.Facts);
randomFact = Array[new Random().nextInt(Array.length)];
```

Also, will I need to split the String if I need to implement Character counting?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wrap_content` in `xml` file.

Eg:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_here"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. You see, it dynamically obtains the string. Hence if let's say a string has about 20-50 characters, it will wrap content. But in the case, a fact has about 70-90 characters, it will undoubtedly fit in the TextView but the layout won't be able to wrap it into it. I need to dynamically, hence change the Size accordingly as per n characters/ words.

Comment: So let's say for 20-50 characters in a string, I use 16 dp as the size of the text. On a character value > x, I want to reduce the size down to 12 dp.

Answer (score 0):

This will show text line by line.

```
<TextView 
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:maxLines="100" 
android:ellipsize="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Best solution @ Edit2**

Not a beautiful solution, but you could count the characters...

```
int count = 0;
for(String s: Array)
    count+=s.length();
```

...and then resize it based on that count, maybe with a factor calculated on startup to relativise it to the width of the screen:

```
textView.setTextSize(factor/count);
```

Now, let's say it should fit perfectly, so if there is one character in the whole string (which better not happens!), it should be as wide as the whole screen, so (factor/1) = maxWidth.

So, the TextView gets width=match_parent in the xml (or of course as big as you'd like it for your app), and on startup you call `maxWidth=textView.getWidth();` -> factor = maxWidth. Or MAXWIDTH, maybe nicer as static(/final).

Edit: Bit more beautiful: After counting, make an if statement to see if you need to resize it at all á la `if(factor/count > minWidth) resize;` to not make a 5-character-string take up the whole screen.

Edit2: This solution goes for one TextView showign all the strings in one line. For one TextView and several lines go

```
int finalCount = 0;
int count = 0;
for(String s: Array){
    count+=s.length();
    if(count>finalCount) finalCount=count;
}
textView.setTextSize(factor(finalCount));
```

Or with different TextView, one for each String, with different sizes, IMO the most beautiful one:

```
int count=0;
for(index i=0;i<Array.length();i++){
    count=Array[i].length();
    textViews[i].setTextSize(factor/count);
    //or directly: textViews[i].setTextSize(factor/Array[i].length());
}
```

Edit4: Actually need dynamic number of TextView here, so go with `myViewGroup.addChild(anotherTextView)` (<-pseudo-code, gotta get the new textview somehow)inside the for loop.

Comment: Beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder. I like this snippet, yet I'm not sure how it will work once implemented. I'll try it out and check. Thanks!

Comment: I just remembered what felt out of place about my solution:
Do you have one String per line aka textView.setText(Array[0]+Array[1]+...+Array[max])? Because then you gotta count each String on its own and then use the biggest count.
My solution goes for one textView to show all strings in one line, which is that wrign thing I meant.

Comment: Updated my answer to a great solution building on my previous.

Comment: Mine contains just one string. Thanks for the effort you're putting in into this.

Comment: Worked with some modifications to my code! Thanks! Cannot vote up as of now due to a lower reputation than 15. Will surely revisit and do it.